# How to solve Garbage Collection error with Picasso in Android

Tags: android, garbage-collection, picasso

I am currently using Picasso to load image from server side and save it in Internal storage in Android. 
I am using the following code to load images from server side:

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                   System.out.println("start run.....");
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(url)
                            .resize(10, 10)
                            .into(new Target() {


                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                    System.out.println("start picasso....");

                                    if (bitmap != null) {
                                        // save image in internal memory

                                        String directory = saveToInternalStorage(bitmap, name);
                                        System.out.println(directory);

                                    } else
                                    System.out.println("image return is null.....");



                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {


                                    System.out.println("Failure in loading photo from server: " + name);


                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                                }


                            });
```

and the following code to save image in memory:

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String imageName){
    System.out.println("start saving image......");
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,imageName);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        boolean save=bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 2, fos);
        System.out.println(save);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Error in saving photo "+e.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Image is successfully saved..."+directory.getAbsolutePath());
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

However, my problem is with Garbage Collection. Picasso does not start at all, even I do not get any failure message from Picasso, and I face with following error :

D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 11% free 12767K/14215K, paused 14ms+25ms, total 118ms

I would be thankful, if anyone suggest me any solution to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

this is not error instead this is information from GC saying GC_CONCURRENT has freed memory which is 434K and took 25ms. There is Google IO talk I would recommend you watch [it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

**"Picasso does not start at all".** Are you not able to load image at all ?

I am not sure if you are facing any problem regarding loading of the image or saving to your internal storage. As much I can guess you are able to do it and the message which you think is error is your problem.

If I am not getting it right. I would pledge you to draft you question in more specified way.

*hope this will help!*

Comment: I used System.out.println("start picasso...."), for onBitmapLoaded of Picasso but it does not print anything. But on my REST service, i can understand that the image is called.

Comment: make me clear on two points.
1) Are you able to load image ?? 
2) is it not getting into onBitmapLoaded ? Did you tried to debug with breakpoints ?

Comment: I mean the Picasso make the connection with server but maybe the Garbage Collection does not allow the image be loaded into phone. I face with following message in debug: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms